# vscode setting tomcat 9 runtime

Tags: java, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get a Tomcat 9 development environment (with maven) set up under vscode (on linux). I am cursed by partial functionality. And every time I try, I get a different variation on broken...

I have come to the conclusion that it all comes down to the inclusion of jars. I have the vscode plugins installed for Java, Maven, Tomcat, etc. The environment works. Only partially.

e.g. @WebServlet cannot resolve to a type. But the annotations-api.jar is in the Tomcat 9 lib folder...

Can someone please explain how to add the Tomcat 9 lib folder as a Server Runtime?

Perhaps if I had a better understanding of this I could fix my broken Eclipse install...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working with the pom.xml below...

Lessons learned:

- Eclipse does everything for you, somewhat sheltering you from the tedious task of including libraries. With vscode, you need to do it yourself. So you may completely forget to import something important.
- Tomcat's error messages are often not very useful in either case.
- As much as I dislike Eclipse, it does do a lot of useful work for you. Vscode is a lot more work...
- I do like vscode a lot. But for Tomcat, it's not as powerful...

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>example.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>test1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.50</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.50</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.50</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.53</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.50</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>test1</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>      <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Not sure how helpful this was... -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <contextFile>src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml</contextFile>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your current project uses no build tools, add the required jar to **Referenced Libraries**.

If you use maven, the extension **Maven for Java** also supports searching Maven Central to resolve unknown types in your source code. You can do this by selecting the `Resolve unknown type` link shown on hover, or you can search the required dependency from **Command Palette--> Maven: Add a dependency**.

Detailed information please view [Add a jar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_add-a-jar) and [Maven in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build#_maven).